# Place Index/Table of Content without page break

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex

I want to remove the page break forcefully inserted by `\tableofcontents` and so far I have not had much success browsing through forums/StackExchange.
[I have added page border only to show separation of pages]

[image: Sample Page Output]

In the sample image I have posted, I want the contents of page 2 to appear in the centre right after `State of Uttar Pradesh and Others` (given on pg 1).

I am using XeTeX and here is the relevant section from my code.

I have written a custom Class file called `vakalatnama.cls`, in which I have:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{vakalatnama}[2020/09/15 Vakalatnama template for Indian courts]

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage[driver=xetex,a4paper,noheadfoot,includeheadfoot,nomarginpar,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in,left=1.75in,right=1.0in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{xunicode}
% \RequirePackage{xltxtra}

% Make entries in the index table as links
\RequirePackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

% Set font to Times New Roman
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% line spacing = 1.5
\RequirePackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\RequirePackage[parfill]{parskip}

% Format section title to have numbers in Table of Contents, but not in document
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\center \normalfont \bfseries}{}{0pt}{\newpage}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\RequirePackage{fontenc}
\hyphenation{con-sti-tu-tion-al}

% Set title of Table of Contents from Contents -> Particulars. '*' implies that
% the argument must not be in multiple paragraphs i.e. /long
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{
    \centering{\underline{\textsc{\large{Index}}}} \\
    \parbox{25pt}{\textbf{Si. No.}} \hfill \underline{\textbf{Particulars}} \hfill \underline{\textbf{Page}}
}

\newcommand{\dhc}{Delhi High Court}
\newcommand{\sci}{Supreme Court of India}
\newcommand{\petitioner}[1]{\newcommand{\@petitioner}{#1}}
\newcommand{\respondent}[1]{\newcommand{\respndt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\court}[1]{\newcommand{\crt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\jurisdiction}[1]{\newcommand{\jurisdctn}{#1}}
\newcommand{\petitiontype}[1]{\newcommand{\ptntype}{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand {\setname} {O{Shri} m m} { % Title (default=Shri), first, last
    \newcommand {\tfname} {#1 #2 #3} % Full name with title
    \newcommand {\fname} {#2 #3} % first + last name
    \newcommand {\tlname} {#1 #3} % title + last name
}

\newcommand{\advocate}[2][Shri]{
    \newcommand{\adv}{#2}
    \newcommand{\fulladv}{#1 #2}
}


\newcommand{\clientdetails}[1]{\newcommand{\clntdtls}{#1}}

\newcommand{\caseNumbers}[2]{
    \newcommand{\fullcasenumber}{#1 of #2}
    \newcommand{\shortcasenumber}{#1/#2}
}


\newcommand{\caseTitle}{
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{In the \crt{}} \newline
        \textsc{\jurisdctn{}} \newline
        \textsc{\ptntype{} \fullcasenumber{}} \newline
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\inmatterof}{%
    % \begin {flushleft}
        \begin{tabular}{l c r}
             \multicolumn{3}{l}{\underline{\textsc{In the matter of:}}}  \tabularnewline
             \tabularnewline
             \@petitioner & \ldots & Petitioner \tabularnewline
             & -- \textsc{versus} -- & \tabularnewline
             \respndt & \ldots & Respondent \tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
   % \end{flushleft}
}

\newcommand{\parties}{%
    \begin {center}
        \begin{tabular}{l c r}
             \@petitioner & \ldots & Appellant/Petitioner \\ %\tabularnewline
             {} & -- \textsc{Between/And} -- & {}  \\ %\tabularnewline
             \respndt & \ldots & Defendant/Respondent/Opposite Party \\ % \tabularnewline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\tophead}{%Roll the Court Name, petition etc into a single command
    \caseTitle{}
    \inmatterof{}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\endinput
```

And there is a separate tex file called `cover.tex` which contains:

```
\tophead{}
\tableofcontents
\vfill*
\textbf{Advocate for the Respondent: \respndt{}}
```

There is a third file called `main.tex` which only provides the parameters for these functions and that is the file I use for compilation. The contents of `main.tex` are:

```
\documentclass{vakalatnama}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}

\petitioner{Test Petitioner}
\court{Supreme Court Of India}
\respondent{State of Uttar Pradesh and Others}
\jurisdiction{Criminal Appellate Jurisdiction}
\petitiontype{SLP (Civil)}
\caseNumbers{1152}{2000}

\input{cover.tex}
\section{yyy} 
\section{zzz}
\end{document}
```

I will be very *very* grateful for any help on this.

Comment: you make it very hard for anyone to help if you only post fragments not a test document that can be debugged, but your inmatterof isn't a heading just a flushleft environment so will have vertical space (and a legal page break point) after it, you don't show any code at all for `\tableofcontents` but if that is making an unbreakable box such as a tabular then it will have to break at the point you show, you could force the page break earlier by adding `\clearpage` at the point you want the page break.

Comment: Hello David - Thank you for your comment. I have added more details, earlier I had not posted them in order to keep the post short and to-the-point.

Comment: but we still can not run the example to see the problem. or test answers, you could remove the `\input`  lines and replace by just enough `\section{zzz}` to show the page break you are asking about. Also you have said you do not want the page break where it is, but do you want it earlier so the preceding text comes at the top of the page, you presumably do not want it to break after the *Particulars* heading row, and  there does not look to be space to get any of the table of contents rows on that page as it is?

Comment: Thank you for your comment and being so patient with me David. I added the suggested edits. In short, I want the `Index` (which is the title I chose for Table of Contents) to appear on the first page (after the line starting with `State of Uttar Pradesh`). I removed the other two lines with `\input` and I have given the contents of `cover.tex` file in my question

Comment: I still don't understand where you want the page break to happen,  Between `State of Uttar Pradesh` and the bottom of the page where `1` appears there is not space to get the Si No title line and at least one line of the table of contents list.  note that all `zzzname` macros should just have text, for easy translation not formatting so putting formatting in `\contentsname` is bad style really (although it usually works)

Comment: I tried your example and got `! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \petitioner`

Comment: perhaps you just want `\begin{center}Index\end{center}` ???

Comment: Your example code can not be run but I guess you want to replace `\hfill \underline{\textsc{Index}} \hfill \\ ` by `\par\noindent\hspace*{\fill}Index\hspace*{\fill}\\*`

Comment: Hi David - can't thank you enough for suffering through my beginner level mistakes. In my attempt to be succinct, I have been missing critical details. I had cropped the image to take up less space here. I have shown my full image now and you will see there is plenty of space to add the table of contents on page 1. I want to put the table of content showing up on page 2, to be on page 1.

Comment: in article class sections do not start on a new page but you are forcing that with `\titleformat{\section}{\center \normalfont \bfseries}{}{0pt}{\newpage}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note it is bad style to put formatting in `\zzzname` macros, they were introduced specifically to separate the text name from formatting, so they can be easily translated without having to copy formatting, however I am not suggesting changing that here.

White space at the beginning of a line is dropped this includes `\hfill` which is why your Index is flush right. `\hspace*` is a variant of `\hspace` that prevents this so:

```
\par\noindent\hspace*{\fill}Index\hspace*{\fill}\\*
```

would centre the text.

`\tableofcontents` in `article` class is a `\section*` so is affected by your declaration

```
\titleformat{\section}{\center \normalfont \bfseries}{}{0pt}{\newpage}
```

which forces a new page. If you want later sections to have this but not in the frontmatter use

```
\newcommand\secpagebreak{}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering \normalfont \bfseries}{}{0pt}{\secpagebreak}
```

so it starts off doing nothing,then at some point do

```
\renewcommand\secpagebreak{\clearpage}
```

so following sections start on a new page (and prevent floating figures flowing past that point with `\clearpage` rather than just `\newpage`).